# force https except one page/post

Tags: single, https

I've spent many hours trying to get this to work; I've read endless posts and tried hundreds of combinations. I'm using a KVM vps so I can edit the apache config files directly if needed.

All I want to do is force https across my whole site (Easy) and exclude one page/post
 needs to be

I assume it's Wordpress's own permalink rewrite thats tripping me up some how.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try rewrite rules? Check this our as reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921192/force-single-site-to-use-https-all-other-http-wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used this in the functions file in the end

```
function force_ssl()
{
    // Specify ID of page to be viewed on SSL connection
if (is_page(8616) && !is_ssl () )
{
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
  header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
  exit();
}
// All other pages must not be https
else if (!is_page(8616) && is_ssl() )
{
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
}
}      
add_action('template_redirect', 'force_ssl');
```